# My Android APP Supported 0 devices

Tags: android, google-play

I try to contact the google play support, they tell me to delete some unnecessary features and permissions. Now there are only 4 basic features and 7 permissins, but it still shows support 0 devices. 
[This is what I see on Google Play.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVnKT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, APP supported 0 devices, because of the feature : android.hardware.autofocus . 
After I delete this feature, it support 11183 devices now.